# UPDATE table column in MySQL for html_entity_decode

Tags: html, mysql, decode

I want to set a column in my mysql database with the function html_encode_entity.
I try to give this command:

```
"UPDATE bibliografie SET Titolo = html_entity_decode(Titolo)"
```

but it gives me the error

```
"#1305 - FUNCTION bib4.html_entity_decode does not exist".
```

Any suggestion please? Which is the correct command?
Thank you.

Comment: `html_entity_decode` is PHP functions, MySQL knows nothing about it. Provide the output of `html_entity_decode(Titolo)` as parameter value for `'UPDATE bibliografie SET Titolo = ?'`. If you want to process/replace the value already stored in the table then retrieve the value to PHP, process then update.

Comment: Recommendation. SELECT table data to CSV. Load to PHP, parse, process the value, save to new CSV. Truncate table and load processed data.

Comment: thank you very much, I think this is the better way.